# Unable to implement onclick event on HTML element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 10 elements. At first I want to shuffle the array elements and display them (my current code does this). Then I want to show an `alert` message if any of the displayed array elements are clicked. This is the thing I am having problem with. If, I am doing `onclick`, it's showing me only 1 array element instead of all the 10 array elements and also showing the following error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`. My code is (I am using only `javascript`):

```
 <script>
    function shuffleArray(array) {
            for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                }
            return array;
        }

    var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];

    newArray = shuffleArray(myArray);

    for (i=0;i<newArray.length;i++) {
        var p = document.write(newArray[i] + "<br >");
                    p.onclick = showAlert; // this is showing me only 1 array element and also showing error in concole
    }

             function showAlert() {
                      alert("onclick Event detected!")
             }
 </script>
```

Comment: You're writing out a String then trying to associate an `onclick` handler with it. You need to create an actual tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an actual element, rather than trying to bind events to strings:

```
for (i=0;i<newArray.length;i++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = newArray[i];
    p.onclick = showAlert; 
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92fRb/1/

Comment: This works, but the `drawback` is, if I click anywhere on the page along the width (row) which have the array elements displayed, the `alert` message pops up. I want the `alert` message to be displayed only if the `array elements` are clicked not if even I click a few distance apart the `array elements`

Comment: @user2567857 Well, p-tags renders as `block`. You can either render an `inline` element, or adjust them to `display: inline-block` if your browser supports it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<newArray.length;i++){
    var p = document.write("<span class='no'>"+newArray[i] + "</span><br />");
}

function showAlert(){
    alert("onclick Event detected!")
}

for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("no").length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("no")[i].onclick=showAlert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Here's your problem... `p` is undefined.
Why?
Because [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) does not return a DOM element. Actually it does not return anything at all (or, returns `undefined`).

You want to:

1. Use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create an element.
2. Use [`p.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) to set the content (inner HTML) of your new element.
3. Append your new element to the document.

Your code can be revised as suggested in [@Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561800/1365324).